# A doubt regarding the Jacobian in multivariable calculus

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Let $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ be continuously differentiable on some open set containing $a\in\mathbb R^n$. Suppose $\det Jf(a)\neq0$.

This is the hypothesis. Actually this is part of the proof of Inverse Function Theorem, available [here](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/%7Enwallach/inverse%5B1%5D.pdf).

Now the proof begins:

> Let $L=J f(a)$. Then $\det L\neq0$, so $L^{-1}$ exists. Consider the composite function $L^{-1}f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$. Then,
>
> $J(L^{-1}f)(a)=J(L^{-1})(f(a)).Jf(a)=L^{-1}.Jf(a)=L^{-1}.L=I$

I don't understand how the second equality came about i.e. how $J(L^{-1})(f(a)).Jf(a)=L^{-1}.Jf(a)$ is true. I understand the first quality is a consequence of composition of jacobians which states that jacobians run through the compositions.

Comment: $L^{-1}$ is linear. The Jacobian of a linear map (at any point $x$) is the linear map itself, $J(L^{-1})(x) = L^{-1}$.

Comment: Okay. I got it. Thank you :)

Comment: The proof cited seems like an awkward way to go: Why not just stay in the realm of linear transformations? It's so much easier.